# What is difference between grains and seeds?

Tags: word-meaning

What is the difference between **grains** and **seeds**?

> Both diets include lots of vegetables and fruits; whole **grains**; nuts
>   and **seeds**; and more seafood than meat.

Comment: What is your native language please?

Comment: My native language is Russian.

Answer (score 3):

Grains specifically refer to the seeds of grasses such as wheat, barley, millet, etc. that can be ground into flour. Just mentioning seeds usually refers to seeds that are eaten individually, like sunflower, almonds, walnuts, etc. It's broken up that way in a dietary sense because the former is valued for its carbohydrate load, whereas the latter are more prized for their 'good' fats.

Comment: When referring to food, almonds and walnuts are nuts, not seeds per se. However, almonds and walnuts can be used as seeds for planting them as plants.  Sunflower seeds are eaten and also planted. They are not a nut.

Comment: What do you mean - 'good' fats?

Comment: @Carduus Pig fat is bad fat (full of cholesterol, for example.) Here is a description of the good oils (in nuts and seeds):https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/heart-disease/in-depth/nuts/art-20046635